# How to change Public Address of VPS with another IP Address

Tags: router, vps, route, ip-routing

For a project, I need to make HTTP requests to an external service from a IP address geo-located on "NATION_2".

Having an available VPS located in NATION_1, I proceeded to purchase a public IP address geo-located in the correct country.

How can I change the routing of the VPS network card to use the new geo-localized IP in the NATION_2 as public IP address, instead of the default public IP address?

The Operating System installed on the VPS is Ubuntu 18.04 Server.

Comment: Are you provisioning this from a cloud platform?  If so, which one?

Comment: Yes, the provider is Ovh.

Comment: @Fede91 Have you found the solution to this?